# Extended Event definition information for a stopped session

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, extended-events

I am trying to get configuration information, via T-SQL, about existing, stopped extended-event sessions.  If the session is started, then the `sys.dm_xe_session_object_columns` DMV gives me exactly what I'm looking for.  Is that information available somewhere for stopped sessions?

Comment: Have you looked at the sys.server_event_session* DMVs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended event catalog views fall under both sys.dm_xe* and sys.server_event_* views. The "active" or "running" event sessions have information stored in sys.dm_xe* (also global package metadata) views and overall server defined metadata stored in sys.server_event_* views regardless of state.

Specifically since the question was about information on extended event sessions that aren't currently running, the metadata for that still exists and the basics of it can be found in [sys.server_event_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-event-sessions-transact-sql) catalog view. Joining this with other catalog views such as [sys.server_event_session_events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-event-session-events-transact-sql), [sys.server_event_session_actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-event-session-actions-transact-sql), and [sys.server_event_session_targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-event-session-targets-transact-sql) (to name a few) can return most of the information that should be needed.

Comment: Sean none of those dmv give what is in sys.dm_xe_session_object_columns.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It isn't going to be an exact 1-1, you'll have to join them and get the data you want. @Taiob